# CSS Navigation Gap

Tags: html, css

So on my menu bar I created, there's a small gap at the bottom which is displayed in this picture:
[image]

I really want to remove it and I don't know what's causing it to appear at only the bottom, no other edges. Here's my code:

```css
#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

#nav li {
 float: left;
}

#nav li a {
 display: block;
 color: #666;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}

#nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: #ddd;
}

#nav li a.active {
 color: white;
 background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"> 
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">User Management</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Site Management</a></li>
  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
   <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vrh4hpa1/

I didn't see any `padding` which would only cause it to appear at the bottom, maybe I'm blind.

Comment: Technically, you can't have a `ul` as a child of a `ul`. That `ul` that you're floating should either be inside of a `li` or should be placed after the first `ul` is closed.

Comment: It's due to your **nested ul**. I've modified your fiddle. Please see the my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, your html is invalid, you have `ul` directly inside another `ul`. Try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">  
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">User Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Site Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#nav li:last-child {float:right}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrh4hpa1/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the **nested UL** element for the "logout" anchor link. I've updated the CSS code in your jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vrh4hpa1/4/

I simply added a special CSS rule to reduce the top/bottom padding by 1px each.

```
//what you have already
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}

//additional rule for the nested ul element
#nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 13px 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Economica', sans-serif;
}
```

just remove display: block;

Comment: How can I increase the height, so it's exactly the same as the jsfiddle example just not using display: block?